# Cant see why my CSS isnt working

Tags: html, css

So ive started learning Web stuff. Im learning Javascript and HTML and CSS. I have made a small web page. Most of my css works fine but I cant see why the very last one isnt working for me.

My HTML for the person-row class is

```
<div class="person-row">
    <img src="images/avatar1.png">
    <div class="person-info">
        <div>Catalina</div>
        <div>sports, pets, party</div>
        <button>Add as a friend</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my css I am trying to get the button to show up on the right of the row so I have

```
person-row > button{
   float: right;
}
```

But the button isnt on the right. Can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Because the parent of `button` is `div.person-info`. Also, `person-row` is a class so you need to write as `.person-row`. You can study more about css selector in http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just a typo in your example above, but `person-row` is missing a period. Should be `.person-row`. And as Shiyou said, `>` is the child selector, and your button isn't a child of `.person-row`.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on here. It is .person-row in my css file. I thought it affected all buttons under person-info, even their childrens?

Comment: Nope, `>` is the child selector. To apply CSS to *all* descendants of an element, just separate them with a space, like `.person-row button`. There, all buttons that are descendants at any level below `.person-row` will have the rules applied.

Comment: okay. That sorts me out. Cheers lads.

Comment: to affect all buttons under .person-info including children you would use .person-row button{
   float: right;
} without the ">"

Answer (score 2):

The reference being specific to a sibling descendant is pretty specific, but it works if it references the correct parent as mentioned in the comments.

Also, there is no . in front of the class identifier as someone mentioned.

Here's the corrected fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ty6cyxvo/

Which contains:

```
<div class="person-row">
    <img src="images/avatar1.png" />
    <div class="person-info">
        <div>Catalina</div>
        <div>sports, pets, party</div>
        <button>Add as a friend</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.person-info > button{
   float: right;
}
```